# What is causing so much nesting in my codeception test call in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, xdebug, codeception

I am trying to run tests in Codeception to test my APIs build using Laravel 5. When I loaded `PhpBrowser` as a dependency for `REST`, it works fine but when I shift it to `Laravel5`, I get a weird error saying:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

I went around the internet and the solution was to edit the `php.ini` file to increase the limit of nesting. So I added this line to my `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

And restarted my server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Yet I am getting the same error when I try to run my test. My `**codeception.yml**` file looks like so:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=carparts'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'admin12345'
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

My `**api.suite.yml**` file looks like so:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:8000/api/
            depends: Laravel5
    config:
        Laravel5:
            cleanup: true
            environment_file: .env.testing
```

And my test looks like so:

```
<?php
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('authenticate a user');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->sendPOST('authenticate', [
    'username' => 'carparts',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();

// Storing a token temporarily to run further tests
$response = $I->grabResponse();
file_put_contents('tests/api/token', json_decode($response)->token);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after going through a number of forums, I found [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-aborting). `rogierverbrugge` was spot on.

So I was trying to edit the wrong files after all. I had to edit `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and add:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
```

And my tests work like a charm now. :)